# Send push notification to dynamic endpoint group with Amazon SNS

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, amazon-sns

In my mobile app users can subscribe to articles/news of different categories, and users will receive push notification whenever new articles of those catories are published.

Right now, the app's push notification are handled by Amazon SNS, i.e. all users subscribed to one topic. However, in this case, as articles can be in more than 1 category, if the notification is handled with the same logic (each category has its own topic ARN), users will end up receiving duplicated notification if he subscribed to two categories, say category A and B, and a new article happens to belong to both category A and B.

To solve this I come up will the following solution:

1. Whenever user register and create their endpoint through with SNS, the endpoint with be saved in our database with regards to that user's ID.
2. When a new article is published, all users subscribed to the article's categories will be retrieved
3. Server will make use of the SNS SDK and subscribes all those retrieved users' endpoints to an empty topic
4. Notification will be sent to that particular topic's channel

While this solution might be feasible for small user population, I imagine that there might be scaling issues when the user population reaches certain scale, i.e. the server might need to call `subscribe()` a hundred thousands times or even more in order to send one push.

Are there any other feasible solution or ways to achieve this with SNS? Thanks!

Comment: it will call until it will call all the endpoints if it more also it has to call otherwise it will send notification for sending notification to single single device it will fetch all the device s and send one by one